# get autocomplete feature with image like imdb.com?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

How to get effect similar to imdb.com  (search textbox).?
i am trying to get image as well as movie name in autocomplete list.but how to make each li as clickable or assign url to each li?

i followed [this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Configuring-jQuery-AutoComplete-Plugin-to-display-Images-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Code i wrote is :

```
$("#<%=txtsearchmovie.ClientID%>").autocomplete("SearchContents.ashx", {
            width:300,
            formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
                return "<img style = 'width:100px;height:100px' src='" + value.split(",")[0] + "'/> " + value.split(",")[1];
            },
            formatResult: function (data, value) {
                return value.split(",")[1];
            }
        });
```

and in ashx i wrote:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["ADO.NET.SqlExpress"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SearchQuery";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}",
                          sdr["ThumbNailUrl"], sdr["MovieName"], sdr["MovieId"], sdr["LanguageType"],Environment.NewLine));
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```

---

ok i tried below code. as well as i updated my site with the code. but i get url only on image or text but not on full li.
as well as i am not able to navigate to url. Result you can see on my site.
I think i need to change the code of js file. 
Code i used in html.

```
 $("#<%=txtsearchmovie.ClientID%>").autocomplete("SearchContents.ashx", {
            width: 250,
            formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
                return "<a class='linkbutton' onclick='' href='" + value.split(",")[4] + "'><img class='ac_poster' src='" + value.split(",")[0] + "'/>" + "<div class='ac_moviename'>" + value.split(",")[1] + "</div></a>";
            },
            formatResult: function (data, value) {
                return value.split(",")[1];
            }
        });
```

ans in ashx i wrote.

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        string newmovie = Convert.ToString(sdr["MovieName"]).Replace(" ", "-");
                        string url = "Movies/"+sdr["LanguageType"]+"-Movies/"+sdr["MovieId"]+"/"+newmovie;
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}{5}",
                         sdr["ThumbNailUrl"], sdr["MovieName"], sdr["MovieId"], sdr["LanguageType"], url,Environment.NewLine));
                    }
                }
```

this returns my url...
if possible please guide me..

Comment: Can you check with some tool the generated html (e.g. with firebug) and paste it here? Does your site is accessible from external url so one can check it and help you with your problem?

Comment: i have not uploaded this code yet in my website it.As it is not working so i have not updated my site.

Comment: ok i have uploaded on http://movie4u.in front page. Now it is working. but how to make each li as clickable or assign url to each li? and how to make text up as it is bottom?

Comment: Here's an easy way to include IMDb's search suggestions on your page: http://web3o.blogspot.com/2011/10/imdb-search-suggestions-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#<%=txtsearchmovie.ClientID%>").autocomplete("SearchContents.ashx", {
  width: 250,
  formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
    // value = "URL,THE TITLE ,##,LANGUAGE"
    var v = value.split(",");
    //  http://movie4u.in/Movies/LANGUAGE-Movies/##/THE-TITLE
    return "<a href='http://movie4u.in/Movies/" + v[3] + "-Movies/" +
      v[2] + "/" + $.trim(v[1].replace(/\s/g,"-")) + "'><img class='ac_thumbs' src='" +
      v[0] + "'/> " + v[1] + "</a>";
  },
  formatResult: function (data, value) {
    return value.split(",")[1];
  }
});
```

With this CSS

```
.ac_results li { font-size: 20px; } 
.ac_thumbs { width:75px; height:75px; vertical-align: middle; }
```